# Recursive function execution strategy

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

From running a basic recursive function, it runs as follows (quite predictably):

```
def count_to_number(n):
    print ('* Calling with n=%s' % n)
    if n == 0:
        print ('** Returning base case with n=%s' % n)
        return 0
    else:
        res = n + count_to_number(n-1)
        print ('*** Returning intermediate result with n=%s ==> %s' % (n, res))
        return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 3
    out = count_to_number(n)
    print ('**** Finished with res=%s' % out)
```

> ```
> $ python recurse.py 
> * Calling with n=3
> * Calling with n=2
> * Calling with n=1
> * Calling with n=0
> ** Returning base case with n=0
> *** Returning intermediate result with n=1 ==> 1
> *** Returning intermediate result with n=2 ==> 3
> *** Returning intermediate result with n=3 ==> 6
> **** Finished with res=6
> ```

How does the compiler (python AST or whatever) know the 'order of operations' for the recursive function to run? For example, why doesn't it evaluate the intermediate before it evaluates the base case?

I'm curious to know how python 'knows' to evaluate one result before the other. Why doesn't, for example, when it sees:

```
count_to_number(3) = 
                   =   3 + count_to_number(2)
                   =   3 + 2 + count_to_number(1) 
                   =   3 + 2 + 1
```

Why doesn't it evaluate it left-to-right?

Comment: Each time you make a function call, the current call is suspended, a new stack frame is created, and execution proceeds with the body of the called function. Whether that function is the same one you are currently executing or another one is irrelevant.

Comment: I’m not sure what you’re asking here. Your intermediate print statement comes after the recursive call, which as you’ve figured out yourself, is basically a substitution. Sequential execution determines the base print statement execution before the intermediate ones, where’s any magic in that?

Comment: @chepner that's probably the clearest explanation I've ever heard on this. Would you want to post an answer with a bit more details and I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you make a function call, the current call is suspended, a new stack frame is created, and execution proceeds with the body of the called function. Whether that function is the same one you are currently executing or another one is irrelevant.

The act of adding new frames to the call stack is a way of implicitly parenthesizing the sum. Your example becomes

```
count_to_number(3) = 
                   =   3 + count_to_number(2)
                   =   3 + (2 + count_to_number(1)) 
                   =   3 + (2 + 1)
                   =   3 + 3
                   =   6
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you ask the same question of this program?

```
n = 3
if n > 0:
    # calling the next iteration with n - 1
    n = n - 1
    if n > 0:
        # again
        n = n - 1
        if n > 0:
            n = n - 1
            if n > 0:
                # nope, it's 0 at this point
                pass
            x = 0
            # returning to the previous iteration, where n = n + 1
            n = n + 1
        x = x + n  # n = 1
        n = n + 1
    x = x + n  # n = 2
    n = n + 1
x = x + n  # n = 3
```

Probably not and that's effectively what your program does.

Answer (score 0):

It does evaluate the expression from left to right. But is goes this way:

```
count_to_number(3) = 
               =   3 + count_to_number(2)
               =   3 + (2 + count_to_number(1))
               =   3 + (2 + (1 + count_to_number(0)))
               =   3 + (2 + (1 + 0))
```

Every recursive function call is stored in a stack. It's not possible to finish a call without finishing the calls within it. That's why the execution of this program goes all the way up to the base case, then the base case returns, which causes the completion of the previous call and so on.